# Testing Asynch Task and Junit

Tags: android, junit

So I was looking around for help on writing an Asynch test and I found alot, but I just don't know how to start.
I want to test a class that extends AsyncTask and only that class. So what should I put in the constructor for the Junit test? It extends InstrumentationTestCase because i need to use restTestonUI.
Sorry if this is dumb question I've never used Junit before.

Comment: u want to know how to start Asynch task??

Answer (score 0):

**start asynch task**

```
NameOfURTask task= new NameOfURTask ();
task.execute();
```

**Your AsyncTask**

```
public class NameOfURTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CueGenius.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("aysnc task...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    //put here what u want to try   

        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```